# PHP Deprecated: WP_RSSjb has a deprecated constructor

Tags: php, functions, widgets

I get messages in the debug.log for PHP Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WP_RSSjb has a deprecated constructor in /home/dccomp/competitions.com/wp-content/plugins/rss-just-better/RSS-just-better.php on line 57.

How can I modify this? The line is

```
class WP_RSSjb extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Widget setup.
 */
function WP_RSSjb() {
 /* Widget settings. */
$widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'rssjustbetter', 'description' => __('A customizable list of feed items given: URL and number of displayable items. Also available as shortcode. Compatible with RSS vers. 0.91, 0.92 and 2.0 & Atom 1.0.', 'RSSjb') );

/* Widget control settings. */
    $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'rss-just-better' );

/* Create the widget. */
    parent::__construct( 'rss-just-better', __('RSS Just Better', 'RSSjb'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `function WP_RSSjb() {` to `function __construct() {`. See [PHP: Constructors and Destructors](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Comment: This change will be reverted if/when a new version (or even the same version) of the plugin is installed. OP should contact the plugin author and tell them to update the plugin to use a PHP >5 constructor.

Comment: Also, whilst not strictly necessary it’s good practice to prefix the declaration with its visibility e.g `public`

Comment: The plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years. The [issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-warning-11/) was posted on the support forums over a year ago.